# How do I send a user id to Google Analytics using the okgrow:analytics package in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, google-analytics

I'm trying to send a userId to Google Analytics in Meteor using the `okgrow:analytics` package. Using the Google Analytics Debugger Chrome extension, I have determined that the userId is not being sent. (I have also set up a dedicated userId view in Google Analytics following the steps [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123666?hl=en)).

In the `okgrow:analytics` documentation it is stated: "...this package will automatically track when a user logs in and logs out. Logging in will call identify on the user and associate their Meteor.userId to their previous anonymous activities."

Looking through their code, it seems that they didn't set the `integrations` options to include Google Analytics. After seeing this I tried calling `analytics.indentify(Meteor.userId(), {integrations: {"Google Analytics": true}})` in the callback of `Meteor.loginWithPassword`, but still no userId was sent.

Answer (score 3):

I opened an issue on Github, and the solution was to change the Google analytics settings in the `settings.json` file to:

```
'Google Analytics' : {'trackingId': <ga-id>, 'sendUserId':true}
```